# perspective*lookAt transformation in qt openGL behaving unexpectedly not even keeping w==1

Tags: qt, opengl, perspective

I am attempting in an openGL window to identify whether or not the
mouse pointer is situated within a given 3D rectangle visible within the rendered scene.

## The story so far

The rectangle's coordinates I already have as world coordinates.
I also have the matrix

```
QMatrix4x4 camera = perspective(..) * lookAt(..)
```

And it seems fine within my vertex shader. After all, using

```
gl_Position = camera * v_vertices;
```

has the rectangle displayed on the screen just like I want it.

## The problem

What I truly want is the screen coordinates of the rectangle's corners
**(xj,yj)** in **[-1,1]^2** on the CPU.

Reassured by my experiences with the vertex shader I first grab

```
QVector4D w = (world coordinates of such a visible vertex) = (xw,yw,zw,1)
```

the values within w looking good in the debugger, gdb. Next I try to directly obtain the screen coordinates using

```
QVector4D s = camera * w
```

since the rectangle actually is rendered on the screen with this very same transformation and since I am deeply believing that all visible openGL points live in **[-1,1]^3** I really would expext an

```
s in ([-1,1],[-1,1],[-1,1], 1)
```

however, I get stuff like

```
w == {xp = 0.5, yp = 1.5, zp = 2, wp = 1}
s == {xp = 1.53, yp = -6.43, zp = 1.81, wp = 2.60}
```

where not even the **s.wp** value stayed at 1.

I guess the question boils down to: How can it be that a visible
vertex on the screen leads to s NOT in ([-1,1],[-1,1],[-1,1], 1)
with my CPU sided reconstruction workflow?

## The particulars

The sheer product camera*w is correct. Given that camera is row-major
I can reproduce in octave:

```
camera = [1.54,  -0.31, -0.29, -0.28;
          0.51,   0.95,  0.87,  0.87;
          0.00,   2.20, -0.41, -0.41;
          0.00, -12.09,  1.48,  2.27]';

w=[.5,1.5,2,1]';

(camera*w)' == 1.5350  -6.4200   1.8200   2.6150
```

Viewer data:

```
site = [0, 0, 5.5]
direction_of_view = [-0.28, 0.87, -0.41]
dir_up = [0,0,1]
near = 0.40
far = 200
fov_v = 45 degrees
fov_h = approx. 65 degrees
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to divide each vector by its `w` component.

This is done automatically during the resterization step in openGL but if you calculate locations manually you need to do it yourself.

Comment: It's as simple as that, isn't it? I wasn't aware of that requirement... but that is why I love this forum. Adding this s/=s.w() to my code has in fact the resulting vector looking good in ([0,1]^3,1). Thank you for your fast reply! :-)